# Subject pronoun after verb

Tags: optative-mood

"Perish the two hands of Abu Lahab [an uncle of the Prophet], and perish he!"

*Perish* is verb and *he* is a subject pronoun, so why is "perish he!" used here?

Comment: It's archaic English word order. (As is the subjunctive mood of *perish*.) EIther this was written long ago, or it was written to sound as if it were written long ago.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  It appears that you are quoting a sentence from a publication. Please provide the name & other details of the publication, and preferably a web-link to the relevant part of the publication: context can be important in answering Qs like this.

Comment: It first part refers to perishing the hands and the latter refers to the person.

Comment: This sounds as though it might be a translation from Arabic. If that's the case how old is the translation, and is the word order similar in the Arabic?

Comment: Think of it as "May he perish". This construction is called 'optative', a minor clause type used to express wishes. Some optatives are subjunctives, as is your example.